# If a graph has $15$ vertices, one with degree $8$, $6$ with degree $6$, $8$ with degree $4$, is it a planar graph?

Tags: graphs, planar-graphs

The question is as above.
I want to prove that there exists a $K_5$ as a subgraph, so this graph is not a planar graph. But I failed.
If you can help me, I will be very appreciative.

Comment: I didn't quite get which degrees you know. Your know there are two vertices with degree 8, and two from degree 6 and one from 4?

Comment: The _degree sequence_ is (8,6,6,6,6,6,6,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4).

Comment: A non-simple disconnected planar graph with that degree sequence is the graph that has the vertex of degree $8$ connected to the vertices of degree $4$. Then pairs of the vertices of degree $4$ have their remaining edges connected to one of the degree $6$ vertices. The two remaining vertices of degree $6$ are connected to each other in a separate connected component. Do you have additional information about the graph? Does it have to be simple? Does it have to be connected?

Comment: What I think is unmentioned so far that should be made explicit is that your description is a set of graphs, rather than a unique graph (until shown otherwise). So there are *three* possibilities, rather than just a true/false: there could be none, some, or only planar graphs in this set.

Comment: @plop assuming it is simple, you can show that it must be connected and that every face borders exactly three edges.

Comment: @orlp I think we can assume that this is homework and that the "actual" question is "show that it is not planar".

Comment: @PålGD The condition of being simple is not mentioned in the post.

Comment: @plop but then it's trivially true, no?

Comment: I am sorry that I came late. The origin of this problem is not clear. I heard it in a telegram group. I think @orlp is right. There could be none, some, or only planar graphs in this set. So let's have an open  mind for this problem. What if it is simple? What if the only information we know is that it is a graph. Let's find answers for all these problems. It might be tedious. But I think it is cool.